# Что значит выросла корона?

Tags: фраза

Это вроде как человек загордился?

Context: "после получения диплома, у него тройная корона выросла."

Comment: When asking for meaning of a set phrase, please provide some use context. This will help others get the idea of how is the phrase used. Thanks!

Comment: In this context, it probably means general disapproval by the speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не знаю источника происхождения этого выражения и можно ли его признать уже оформившимся фразеологизмом, но мне оно понятно без связи с какими-либо блогами, как вариант выражения ***корона не упадёт*** и ему подобных.

Слово **корона** в современном разговорном языке, насколько я заметил, приобрело переносное значение *завышенного самомнения*, *заносчивости*, т.е. архетипически королевских замашек, или используется для саркастического и пренебрежительного обозначения чувства собственного достоинства и самоуважения в негативных высказываниях.

Поэтому я понимаю предложение в том смысле, что после получения диплома у человека непропорционально и неоправданно выросла самооценка, человек стал себя переоценивать, стал заноситься, задрал нос.

---

В [1999 г.](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1990%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2002&ei=FHkZW62rIMKVsgGw_oPwBw&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.9882.11674.0.12129.6.6.0.0.0.0.182.494.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.2.329...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i7i5i30k1.0.taRQ2xBqTCU) Гугл впервые фиксирует выражение **"корона не упала"**

> Ни у кого **корона не упала** перевестись на заочное и пойти работать,
>   растить и СОДЕРЖАТЬ детей, работать и получать высшее

а **"корона не упадёт"** впервые фиксируется в [2002 г.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%22&newwindow=1&biw=1279&bih=891&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1990%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2002&tbm=)

> Но, как говорится, с их головы **корона не упадет**, если они признают,
>   что ни одно открытие их в этом направлении современной науке не
>   принадлежит.

Выражение **"корона выросла"** впервые Гуглом зафиксировано в [2005 г.](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1279&bih=891&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1990%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2008&ei=vXsZW-mcCLSSmgX13rzwCA&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1j0i8i30k1l2.47101.48318.0.48732.7.7.0.0.0.0.330.896.0j2j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.2.516...0i19k1j0i7i30i19k1.0.O5mjcaCbmGY)

> Спасибо за совет дорогие домовые только дельного мало, вы что с
>   посторонними вообще не общаетесь или **корона выросла**?

следующая фиксация - только в 2008 г.

> Так вот у девушки-мастера в какой-то момент такая **корона выросла**, что
>   это стало отражаться на обслуживании клиентов.

В утвердительной форме **"корона упала"** со смыслом "перестать важничать, стать проще" и "унизиться" впервые фиксируется в [2012 г.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&newwindow=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/2012,cd_max:12/31/2012&ei=WXEZW57hJsOCgAbC-6_wBQ&start=0&sa=N&biw=1279&bih=891)

> О, да! Моя доча 3,5 лет на себе ощутила тайскую любоффь))) Она всё
>   время была в недоумении, почему, кроме мамы и папы, её тискают
>   незнакомые иностранные граждане ))))....Ну, а дома то **"корона упала"** и
>   она еще долго вспоминала дружелюбный тайский народ.

> странно, конечно, 2 минуты сидеть и записывать - это по-мужски,
>    йоптыть... выйти и помочь - **это ж корона упала бы, да**?

Answer (score 2):

This term is employed in narrow context of a [popular Russian relations psychology blogger](https://evo-lutio.livejournal.com/). In that context it (very roughly) means a sudden build-up of illusions of self-importance to other party.

Не "загордился", а скорее "перестал видеть настоящее отношение к себе и стал видеть выдуманное".

When used outside of this context it might mean anything.

Comment: seems to me this blogger has some influence on the language dynamics

Comment: @J.Doe Russian blogosphere (and, before that, personal computing enthusiasts) has enormous influence on Russian language. Before that, drug addicts :)